# Unable to get ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server on Raspbian 10 (Buster)

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, debian, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am trying to install "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" on my raspberry pi without success.

## 1 This is what i tried

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3

RUN apt-get update

1. Install dependencies for PyODBC and tds
RUN apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt install unixodbc-bin -y
RUN apt-get clean -y
2. Edit /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "[FreeTDS]\n\
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver\n\
Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n\
Setup = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/odbc/libtdsS.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
3. Install requirements (contains pyodbc)
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
Copy and run my app
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "app.py"]
```

My code:

```
import pyodbc 
def inserare(operator,loc_munca,comanda,stare,data,ora,bucati):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=database;UID=pi;PWD=pass')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into Pontaj values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",operator,loc_munca,comanda,stare,data,ora,bucati)
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Error from python shell

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib >'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Error from terminal

> sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin unixodbc-dev tdsodbc
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package tdsodbc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Unable to locate package freetds-dev
>
> E: Unable to locate package freetds-bin
>
> E: Package 'tdsodbc' has no installation candidate

Comment: "FreeTDS" and "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" are completely different things. What you have been attempting is to set up FreeTDS ODBC (`apt` package `tdsodbc`) and that hasn't worked because apparently it is not in the repositories for your Linux distribution. Therefore, you'll probably have to [build FreeTDS from source](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/build.htm).

Comment: @GordThompson all i want is to put ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Serve on my debian

Comment: ... and what version of "debian" is that? If you are unsure then the output from `lsb_release -a` might be helpful.

Comment: @GordThompson No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster

Comment: Okay, so have a look at the [installation instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#debian-8-and-9) for "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server". Debian 10 is not included, so it is not (yet) available for that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolved the issue by modifying odbc.ini and odbcinst.in on /etc.
I was able to connect to the database after modifying those files.
I think that the ODBC 17 comes blank and that's the issue.

## odbc.ini

```
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = My Test Server
Trace = No Server
Name = mssql
Port = port
instance = ip\SQLEXPRESS
Database = yourdatabase
TDS_Version = 4.2
```

## odbcinst.ini

```
Description=FreeTDS 
Driver v0.91
Driver=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsS.so
fileusage=1
dontdlclose=1
UsageCount=1
```